# MySQL row lock and atomic updates

Tags: mysql, rowlocking

I am building a "poor man's queuing system" using MySQL.  It's a single table containing jobs that need to be executed (the table name is `queue`).  I have several processes on multiple machines whose job it is to call the `fetch_next2` sproc to get an item off of the queue.

The whole point of this procedure is to make sure that we never let 2 clients get the same job.  I thought that by using the `SELECT .. LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE` would allow me to lock a single row so that I could be sure it was only updated by 1 caller (updated such that it no longer fit the criteria of the `SELECT` being used to filter jobs that are "READY" to be processed).

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I just had some instances where the same job was given to 2 different processes so I know it doesn't work properly.  :)

```
CREATE DEFINER=`masteruser`@`%` PROCEDURE `fetch_next2`()
BEGIN
    SET @id = (SELECT q.Id FROM queue q WHERE q.State = 'READY' LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE);

    UPDATE queue
    SET State = 'PROCESSING', Attempts = Attempts + 1
    WHERE Id = @id;

    SELECT Id, Payload
    FROM queue
    WHERE Id = @id;
END
```

Comment: Why so mych trouble to build a poor man's queue? Why not use a real queue. Lot less sweat

Comment: @middlestump: But it's less than 10 lines of code. :) Besides, I'd really like to understand how this row-locking works in MySQL for other projects too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code for the answer:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`masteruser`@`%` PROCEDURE `fetch_next2`()
BEGIN
    SET @id := 0; 
    UPDATE queue SET State='PROCESSING', Id=(SELECT @id := Id) WHERE State='READY' LIMIT 1;

    #You can do an if @id!=0 here
    SELECT Id, Payload
    FROM queue
    WHERE Id = @id;
END
```

The problem with what you are doing is that there is no atomic grouping for the operations. You are using the [SELECT ... FOR UPDATE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html). The Docs say that it blocks "from reading the data in certain transaction isolation levels". But not all levels (I think).  Between your first SELECT and UPDATE, another SELECT can occur from another thread. Are you using MyISAM or InnoDB? MyISAM might not support it.

The easiest way to make sure this works properly is to [lock the table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html).

---

[Edit] The method I describe right here is more time consuming than using the `Id=(SELECT @id := Id)` method in the above code.

Another method would be to do the following:

1. Have a column that is normally set to 0.
2. Do an "UPDATE ... SET ColName=UNIQ_ID WHERE ColName=0 LIMIT 1. That will make sure only 1 process can update that row, and then get it via a SELECT afterwards. (UNIQ_ID is not a MySQL feature, just a variable)

If you need a unique ID, you can use a table with auto_increment just for that.

---

You can also *kind of* do this with transactions. If you start a transaction on a table,  run `UPDATE foobar SET LockVar=19 WHERE LockVar=0 LIMIT 1;` from one thread, and do the exact same thing on another thread, the second thread will wait for the first thread to commit before it gets its row. That may end up being a complete table blocking operation though.

Comment: Thank you.  I am using InnoDB.  To receive the bounty award, would you please provide the stored procedure code for the proposed options?

Comment: Is there a specific method of the ones I listed that you would like me to do? The full lock table would be the easiest.

Comment: Since I'm using InnoDB I assume it would only lock one row, right? "If you use InnoDB, it will only lock the row you are working with."  That options sounds fine to me.

Comment: It does row locking for transactions when a row has been updated. I misspoke in what I said, fixing it. a full "lock table WRITE" will completely block the table from all other threads.

Comment: @Dakusen: Hmm, I don't like the idea of locking the whole table.  You can assume there is a `UniqueValue` column for doing as you say to update just a single row.  Instead of `WHERE ColName=0` I think you should just be able to go with `WHERE State='READY'`

Comment: `WHERE State='READY'` can be one of the qualifiers, but since changing its state and getting its ID are not atomic, it can't be the only parameter in the where clause. So you want me to implement the method that requires no locks at all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125386/discussion-between-skb-and-dakusan).